# JQuery Unrecognized expression contains selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm copying some code over from a project that used jQuery v1.11.2 to a new project which uses v3.1.0 and the following line of code doesn't work. I get an unrecognized expression error in the console:

```
$('#createEditTabs a[data-target=#tabEditConfig]').tab('show');
```

This line worked fine in the old project but fails to work in the new updated one. Not sure exactly why or if v3.1.0 has some differences when using contains selectors.

Comment: you need to quote the attribute value `[data-target="#tabEditConfig"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap attribute value with quotes to avoid the issue with `#` in the beginning.

```
$('#createEditTabs a[data-target="#tabEditConfig"]').tab('show');
//                              -^--          --^-
```

---

The attribute value should be a [valid identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) or quoted string. In your code, it's not a [valid identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)(contains `#`) so use quoted string.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. It must be some extra validation added to jQuery for later versions then I guess. Will accept your answer when stack overflow lets me accept it in 5 mins.

Comment: @NiallMitch14 : glad to help :)

Comment: @NiallMitch14 I don't believe anything has changed with the attribute selector recently. It's more likely an amendment to the QuerySelector/QuerySelectorAll implementation of the browser you're using.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't work without the quotes but does work with them like in your answer. Not sure actually.

Comment: @NiallMitch14 :  if the attribute value doesn't contain `#` then it will work without quotes

Comment: I understand now. Thanks!